# getting dnsmasq to issue different ip address for domain name when dhcp client connected

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I am undertaking development of an https application (both client and server) which requires that I issue myself a certificate with the domain name of the server.  Lets say its test.example.com and I access the server from my browser with https://test.example.com

My development machine sits on my home network, with a dhcp/dns server on another machine which uses dnsmasq.  It can be configured to deliver the ip address of my development machine to a dns lookup of test.example.com

BUT.  I have a small raspberry pi which I want to hold a copy of this application.  When I plug it into my home network my dnsmasq recognises its mac address and allocates it a known ip address.

CAN I configure dnsmasq in anyway (or something else?), so that IF and ONLY IF this machine is plugged in a dns lookup of test.example.com now returns this machines ip address.

NOTE: I am happy to give this domain name a very short TTL to facilitate a quick switch over.

NOTE: I am aware that one approach could be to configure the dns server to always return the ip address of raspberry pi, but put test.example.com in my development machines /etc/hosts file for use only when I want develop locally and manually remove it when I want to use the raspberry pi.  I am looking for an automatic solution. (although this will be the fallback if no answer here is forthcoming)

UPDATE:  I have come to the conclusion I have asked the wrong question.  I think I can achieve what I want by using a certificate with more than one domain name it it.  I can then load that single multidomain name certificate in my code and distribute it to both machines.  I then just point the browser at the correct machine and it will run the same copy of the code on the machine I want.  BUT the code is identical on both machines.